# Error when adding styles to a view in odoo 16

Tags: python, odoo, backend, assets, scss-mixins

I've created a module and it works fine, but when I add styles to it I can't install it.HERE I COPY THE SCREENSHOTS TO HELP ME RESOLVE.[Image del manifest.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhMtm.png) [Part of code xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os6Nn.png) [Directory of my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HByNB.png) [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhZ34.png)
Based on the error message, it seems that the problem is related to the external ID "web.assets_backend" not being found in the system. Is there a module that adds that id, is there a way to add it manually? Or is there another way to add styles without using "web.assets_backend" and "web.assets_frontend"? I will be waiting for your answers tried, installed the web module, web_site to see if I can add the external id but nothing works, tried to add styles with other methods but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You'll like get responses if you do not paste images of code.  Here is why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1847378

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing new and old way to change/add assets. Just remove your xml assets part.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/os6Nn.png Greetings, delete the code.
    <!-- Load style files -->
    <data>
        <template id="assets_common" inherit_id="web.assets_common">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <link rel='stylesheet' href="/fiscal_documents/static/src/scss/styles.scss"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/tax_documents/static/src/js/styles.js"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data> and now I can install the module, but the scss and js styles are not applied

Comment: No errors in the odoo server log about that? Your code should work now, like described in the [doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/frontend/assets.html#bundles)

Comment: remove this code: <!-- Load styles files --> <template id="assets_common" inherit_id="web.assets_backend"> <xpath expr="." position="inside"> <link rel='stylesheet' href="/tax_documents/static/src/scss/styles.scss"/> <script type="text/javascript" src="/tax_documents/static/src/ js/styles.js"/> </xpath> </template> and install the module then add it to add the styles and it gives me an error:

Comment: File "E:\Sistema Empresarial\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_model.py", line 2016, in _xmlid_lookup raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid) ValueError: External ID not found in the system: web.assets_backend

Comment: File "E:\Sistema Empresarial\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 711, in _tag_root
    raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, somewhere inside\n%s' % (
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing None:56, somewhere inside
<data inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/documentos_fiscales/static/src/scss/styles.scss"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/documentos_fiscales/static/src/js/styles.js"/>
            </xpath>
        </data>
2023-07-07 14:25:39,014